# Problem with Select List control in asp.net web mobile application

Tags: asp.net, mobile, selectlist

I am trying to develop the single page in asp.net web mobile application as code behind c#.
I have took the Mobile select list control on page.It has items, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...20. I want it should be assign the selected value of select control to mobile label control situated on page (Mobile Form). As per i know I have to code this on OnSelectIndexChanged Event at code behind. ok? but nothing like this happening. I have written the method (Event) on code behind. I don't want to write javscript or on .aspx code ( not want any client code). I want to conduct functionality on code behind. How should I can achieve this.? As I found Select List control of Mobile toolkit not generates the server side event.

What I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set AutoPostBack=true in your select list control in order to fire the OnSelectedIndexChanged event.

**EDIT:**

In looking on Google for 30 seconds, I discovered that a selection of an item in the SelectionList does not fire a server event.

Look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xd15tak%28VS.90%29.aspx.) for a sample on how to raise a server response.

Comment: But there is no such property to select List controls in mobile toolkit.

Comment: There is a property of the SelectionList that lets you indicate that it will be a DropDownList

Comment: anyway..i solved this by using DeviceSpecific :

ASPX Code: 
<code> 
<mobile:Panel ID="Panel1" Runat="server"></code>
<mobile:DeviceSpecific ID="DeviceSpecific1"  Runat="server">
<Choice Filter="supportsJavaScript">
<ContentTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
</Choice>                
</mobile:DeviceSpecific>
</mobile:Panel>

Comment: Code Behind:
DropDownList  selectList = new DropDownList();
if (selectList != null){                        
 selectList.ID = "selectionList" + j;
 selectList.AutoPostBack = true;
selectList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(selectList_SelectedIndexChanged);
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
{selectList.Items.Add("Item :" + k.ToString());}
Panel1.Content.Controls.Add(selectList);
}